# WORDPRESS: Call a plugin function from anotherplugin

Tags: php, wordpress

how can I call a function in a plugin, from another plugin? 
The function I need to call is not in a class

thanks

Comment: See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57043/how-can-i-call-a-function-from-one-plugin-within-another-plugin

Comment: as mentioned, The function I need to call is not in a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that function not inside the class then it's commonly accessible anywhere if that plugin loads that file on initial load.

WordPress loads plugins in Ascending order (by its name)

So you need to load your plugin at the last to allow those plugins to load entire code base and you call that function like below

```
if(function_exists('needed_function')){
  needed_function();
}
```

otherwise just include that file.

```
include_once plugin_dir/that-plugin/file.php
```

now you call that function

Comment: Thank you, I missed the part where I have to include the file prior to call the method, not it works.
Any way to override a global variable inside the method?

Comment: You can override any global var in PHP.